# I want to hide Edit and Delete command column and just show Add new Row option for no data in the grid

Tags: angular

Add new row
              
            
          
          
            
              
                Edit
              
              
                {{ isNew ? 'Add' : 'Update' }}

```
          <button kendoGridRemoveCommand class="k-primary" tabindex="26">
            Delete
          </button>
          <br /><br />
          <button kendoGridCancelCommand class="k-primary" (click)="onCancel()" tabindex="27">{{ isNew ? 'Cancel' : 'Cancel' }}</button>
        </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-command-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NgIf directive, like this:

```
<div *ngIf="dataInTheGrid; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>Content to render when condition is true.</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>
```

To have something like:

```html
<div *ngIf="dataInTheGrid; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>

<ng-template #thenBlock>
  <kendo-grid-command-column>
    <button kendoGridRemoveCommand class="k-primary" tabindex="26">Delete</button>
    <br /><br />
    <button kendoGridCancelCommand class="k-primary" (click)="onCancel()" tabindex="27">Update</button>
  </kendo-grid-command-column>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <kendo-grid-command-column>
    <button kendoGridCancelCommand class="k-primary" (click)="onCancel()"
      tabindex="27">Add new Row</button>
  </kendo-grid-command-column>
</ng-template>
```